# Inconsistent plotting behaviour with radial bar chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to create a circular bar chart in Python/matplotlib. I have the code working fine on my desktop (using Spyder), but the output of the program is completely different on different computers even in the same version of Python (3.5) and Spyder (3.3.1). The circular bar chart becomes split into a single segment, and I don't understand why.

[What it looks like on my desktop (meant to look like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdjVd.png)

[What it looks like on other computers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikoAS.png)

The code reads in the data from a spreadsheet. It basically extracts the countries and percentage values, and then regions are used for colours.

Example input: [data.xlsx](https://a.uguu.se/qbb4stMr5vHt_data.xlsx)

I have tried making sure the versions of Python are the same and gone through every line of code, and I think its something to do with my call to create the thetagrid (about 10 lines from bottom) which behaves differently depending on the computer. This is where the chart goes from circular into its weird segment behaviour.

```
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plot params
bottom = 0
max_height = 10
DPI = 400
figsize = DPI*8
MaxPercentage = 0.12
MinPercentage = -0.12
Padlength = 45 #This is the maximum country name length

for sheetcount in range(0,2):

    #read in data
    xl = pd.ExcelFile('data.xlsx')
    sheet_names = xl.sheet_names
    currentsheet = sheet_names[sheetcount]
    datafortitle = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname = currentsheet)
    ChartTitle = datafortitle.iloc[0,1]
    rawdata = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheetname = currentsheet,usecols = [0,1,2,3], skiprows = 3)
    rawdata.columns = ['regions','countries','count','value']

    #populate regions (remove gaps)
    for i in range(0,len(rawdata.index)):
        if pd.isnull(rawdata.get_value(i, 'regions')): 
            rawdata.at[i, 'regions'] = rawdata.get_value(i-1,'regions') 


    #remove rows where count isnt 3
    rawdata = rawdata[~pd.isnull(rawdata).any(axis=1)]

    # Get names of indexes for which columns dont have enough data
    indexNames = rawdata[ rawdata['count'] <= 2].index

    # Delete these row indexes
    rawdata.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
    rawdata = rawdata.reset_index(drop = True)

    fulldata = rawdata

    #cut into respective groups
    Regions = fulldata.iloc[:,0].astype(np.str)
    Countries_Lower = fulldata.iloc[:,1].astype(np.str)
    Countries = Countries_Lower.str.upper()
    ActualSalary = fulldata.iloc[:,3].astype(np.float)
    ActualSalaryStr = fulldata.iloc[:,3].astype(np.str)

    N = len(ActualSalary)

    #Set colours for regions
    Colours = ["" for x in range(N)]
    i = -1
    for x in Regions:
        i += 1
        x = str(x)
        if x == 'Africa':
            Colours[i] = '#490E3D'
        elif x == 'APAC':
            Colours[i] = '#E97F02'
        elif x == 'Europe':
            Colours[i] = '#F8CA00'        
        elif x == 'LATAM':
            Colours[i] = '#88C100'
        elif x == 'Middle East':
            Colours[i] = '#30C4C9'
        elif x == 'North America':
            Colours[i] = '#E40D2C'
        else:
            Colours[i] = 'black'        


    TrimmedSalary = ActualSalary.copy()
    TrimLocation = np.zeros(len(ActualSalary))

    #Trim values to be plotted to be less than or equal to MaxPercentage
    for i in range(0,len(ActualSalary)):
        if TrimmedSalary[i] > MaxPercentage:
            TrimmedSalary[i] = MaxPercentage
            TrimLocation [i] = 1
        if TrimmedSalary[i] < MinPercentage:
            TrimmedSalary[i] = MinPercentage
            TrimLocation [i] = 2


    theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False) - np.pi/N
    r = max_height*TrimmedSalary
    width = (2*np.pi) / N

    with plt.rc_context({'font.cursive':'Textile','axes.edgecolor':'#8a8a8a', 'xtick.color':'#8a8a8a', 'figure.facecolor':'white'}):# 'font.family':'cursive','font.sans-serif':'Geneva'}):

        f = plt.figure(figsize=(figsize/DPI,figsize/DPI))                 
        ax = f.add_subplot(111, polar = True)

        #remove y axis clutter, setup x axis.
        ax.xaxis.grid(color = '#8a8a8a', linestyle = '-')
        ax.yaxis.grid(False)
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.set_axisbelow(True)
        ax.FontName = 'Sans'

        #add country labels
        ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,N+1))

        bars = ax.bar(theta, r, width=width, bottom=bottom, edgecolor = "none", linewidth = 0)

        # Use custom colors and opacity
        i = 0
        for r, bar in zip(r, bars):
            bar.set_facecolor(Colours[i])
            bar.set_alpha(1.0)
            i += 1

        Colours.append('black')

        #Fix plot size
        ax.set_ylim([MinPercentage*max_height,MaxPercentage*max_height])

        ############################################
        #Plot labels
        Valuelabels = ["%.2f" % x for x in (ActualSalary*100)] 
        Valuelabels = [s + " %" for s in Valuelabels]
        maxlen = len(max(Valuelabels, key=len))

        angles = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi - 2*np.pi/N,N)
        angles[np.cos(angles) < 0] = angles[np.cos(angles) < 0] + np.pi
        angles = np.rad2deg(angles)
        angleplace = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,N+1)
        angleplace = np.rad2deg(angleplace)

        for i in range(0,N):
            if 90 < angleplace[i] <= 270:
                Valuelabels[i] = Valuelabels[i].rjust(maxlen+1)      
            else:
                Valuelabels[i] = Valuelabels[i].ljust(maxlen+1)


        CombinedLabels = ["" for x in range(N)]

        for i in range(0,N):
            if 0 <= angleplace[i] <= 90:
                CombinedLabels[i] = Valuelabels[i] + Countries[i]
            elif 90 < angleplace[i] <= 270:
                CombinedLabels[i] = Countries[i] + Valuelabels[i]          
            else:
                CombinedLabels[i] = Valuelabels[i] + Countries[i]              


        #Pad to the same length
        maxlen = Padlength        
        for i in range(0,N):
            if 90 < angleplace[i] <= 270:
                CombinedLabels[i] = CombinedLabels[i].rjust(maxlen)      
            else:
                CombinedLabels[i] = CombinedLabels[i].ljust(maxlen)    

        ax.set_xticklabels(CombinedLabels, fontsize=10,)
        plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
        labels = []

        radius = 4    
        i = 0
        for label, angle in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(), angles):   
            x = i/N*(2*np.pi)
            #y = 3.1
            y = 2.77

            lab = ax.text(x,y, label.get_text(), color = Colours[i],
                          ha='center', va='center',
                          weight = 'bold', fontsize = 10,
                          fontproperties=prop)
            lab.set_rotation(angle)
            labels.append(lab)
            i += 1


        #Plot gridlines - SOMETHING GOES WRONG HERE
        thetagrid = np.linspace(0.0, 2*np.pi, N+1) - np.pi/N
        (lines,labelsempty)=plt.thetagrids(np.degrees(thetagrid))

        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.set_axisbelow(False)

        #Add central circle
        circle = pl.Circle((0, 0), 0.4, transform=ax.transData._b, fc="white",ec = '#8a8a8a', zorder = 10)
        ax.add_artist(circle)        

        plt.savefig(ChartTitle, dpi = DPI, bbox_inches='tight')
        #plt.show()
```

Really sorry for all the code, but didn't know how to cut it down.

Is anyone aware of something that I might be missing? A difference in versions perhaps? An update to thetagrid? Or am I just using all this completely wrong.

I really would appreciate any help you might have, as I've been struggling with trying to fix this for a couple of weeks now and have just hit a dead end.

Many thanks.

Comment: `print(matplotlib.__version__)` on both computers.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks. Its 1.5.3 on my desktop and 3.0.3 on my laptop... I guess this could be it. Do you know how I can install a specific version of matplotlib?

Comment: SO the newer version gives the undesired result? One would need  a [mcve] (i.e. runnable  code without external data) to check where exactly the problem is.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, the newer one gives the undesired segment plot, not the full circle. Thank you again, I will try to narrow it down, but I believe the error occurs when I call plt.thetagrids 10 lines from the bottom.

Comment: Give us some sample data so we can reproduce/test. You've dumped a lot of code, but no way to run it.

Comment: @MattMessersmith I have included a link to an example in the post now, thanks

Comment: @MattMessersmith Have you had any chance to look at this? I tried reverting matplotlib to 1.5.3 on my laptop but that just introduced other errors that seemed like version incompatibilities.